# Overwriting resources during maven war overlay

Tags: java, maven, overlay, maven-war-plugin

As I've gathered, `maven-war-plugin` never overwrites files which already exist in the target of an overlay. For example, if I have a `war` **A** which has a dependency on a `war` **B**, both of which contain some resource located at `src/main/resources/some.xml`, the resulting `A.war` will contain the `some.xml` from the **A** project.

How do I instruct the `maven-war-plugin` to favor the resources from the dependency (**B**) over the original ones (**A**)?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just remove the duplicate files from A?

Comment: I agree with @MaxNanasy. Overlays are supposed to be used to define a template for a WAR.

Answer (score 1):

See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html:

> "For instance if the index.jsp file of the overlay *my-webapp* **must** be set in the webapp but other files can be controlled the regular way, define two overlay configurations for *my-webapp*"

```
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <overlays>
        <overlay>
          <id>my-webapp-index.jsp</id>
          <groupId>com.example.projects</groupId>
          <artifactId>my-webapp</artifactId>
          <includes>
            <include>index.jsp</include>
          </includes>
        </overlay>
        <overlay>
          <!-- empty groupId/artifactId represents the current build -->
        </overlay>
         ...
      </overlays>
    </configuration>
```

Guess that's not the final desicion, but a point to start at.

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven-resources plugin to copy a file to the desired location. Before or after a war has been built.